# How to use embedded assembly in x64 mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, assembly, nasm, sse

I am trying to embedded some assembly code into my C++. Everything is fine when I use x86(win32) build mode, but when I switch to x64 build mode, VS2012 reports a lot of compiling errors.

I am wondering how to embed the assembly into C++ in x64 build mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be supported. Quoting from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Inline assembly is not supported on the Itanium and x64 processors.

Comment: Even if MSVC allows inline assembly then 32-bit assembly is not valid 64-bit code, hence can't be run

Answer (score 2):

You can, just not inline. Go to build customizations, add MASM (or YASM if you like it better - I do), then add .asm files. They will be assembled and linked in with no further effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Youtube page called "What's a Creel" or something like that.  He has a fifty-something lesson course on adding assembly to C++ using Visual Studio.